# Losing scope in for loop?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with this bit of code.  In "debug" mode, it seems to work.  However, in release mode, "text" doesn't show up in the locals of the for loop.  I cannot see the text string growing with found hashes.  Any ideas?

```
    std::string checkHashes(std::vector<std::wstring> hashes) {

        std::string text;

        for (int i = 0; i < hashes.size(); i++) {
            if (hashtable[wstring_to_string(hashes[i])] != "") {
                text.resize(text.size() + 33);
                std::string hash = wstring_to_string(hashes[i]);
                text = text + hashtable.find(hash)->second + " ";
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Side-note: In C++, you *really* want to use `text += hashtable.find(hash)->second + " ";` (or better, a two step: `text += hashtable.find(hash)->second; text += ' ';`) not `text = text + `. Using `+` means constructing and destructing tons of progressively larger temporary strings while destroying the older ones as you go. `+=` mutates the string in place, using a growth algorithm that minimizes reallocations.

Comment: Also, the `resize()` is wrong, too.  Get rid of that.  Using either `text = text + ...` or `text += ...` will grow the string according to the size of the string being added to it. Hell, this whole code is inefficient.  You should cache the results of `wstring_to_string()` and `hashtable[]` to local variables so they are invoked only one time per loop iteration instead of twice. And maybe consider using a `std::ostringstream` to collect the concatenated data instead of a `std::string` variable.

Comment: Nrvo? Debugging optimised code is hard (both for you and the debugger).

Comment: Thank you.  I originally had both of your suggestions and these were my attempts to debug :D.  I'll go revert myself.

Comment: @rici Thank you, I think that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably use the debugger in release mode.

If you do want to see what 'text' contains at each iteration you could use std::cout and making it compile conditionally with `#ifdef DEBUG / #endif` or by using a static variable `static bool s_debug = false` which, unlike the conditional compiling, can be changed at runtime.